# DJango Template Not Found Issue

Tags: python, django

Still learning Django and for some reason I have difficulty grasping some concepts especially the url / template / view mappings.  Attempting to reirect a FormView to a "Complete" page I have the following:

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('forgotid/', ForgotId.as_view(),name="forgotid"),
    path('forgotid/complete/',ForgotIdComplete.as_view(),name="forgotid_complete"),
    path('forgotpwd/', ForgotPwd.as_view(),name="forgotpwd")
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import FormView, TemplateView

from .forms import LoginForm, ForgotIDForm


class IndexView(FormView):
    template_name = "login/index.html"
    form_class = LoginForm


class ForgotId(FormView):
    template_name = "login/forgotid.html"
    form_class = ForgotIDForm
    success_url = 'complete/'


class ForgotIdComplete(TemplateView):
    template_name = "login/forgotid/complete/forgotid_complete.html"

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name, None)


class ForgotPwd(TemplateView):
    template_name = "login/forgotpwd.html"
```

submitting the ForgotID form should redirect me to the `success_url` but I get an error stating that the template could not be found.  Can someone please explain what and why I am doing this incorrectly.

The error I am receiving is:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /login/forgotid/complete/
```

My folder structure:
[image]

***EDIT***
I found the issue.  The template name in the ForgotIdComplete class should read: `login/forgotid_complete` and not`login/forgotid/complete/forgotid_complete.html`

Comment: do you have your app in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: @Dragos.  I definitely do.  Thanks.

Comment: Exactly what is your error: the *page* could not be found, or the *template* could not be found? If it is the latter, *is* your template actually in "login/forgotid/complete/forgotid_complete.html"? Show the project structure and the location of that template.

Comment: @Daniel  Updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

change your success_url to this.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

class ForgotId(FormView):
    template_name = "login/forgotid.html"
    form_class = ForgotIDForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('forgotid_complete')
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that, django wanted to `render` the template from the path you provided but couldn't find it on the disk.

Go to `settings.py` and make sure that `templates` is configured to your actual templates directory.

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.realpath('.')
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [(os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'))],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The template name in the `ForgotIdComplete` class should read:
`login/forgotid_complete` 
and not
`login/forgotid/complete/forgotid_complete.html`